# routing all traffic of wireless connection through a middlebox or alike in windows 7

Tags: windows, networking, proxy, wireless-networking, routing

I have a net connection with proxy enabled and I am trying to find a way to route all traffic from a wireless hotspot that i create on my laptop to go through a particular proxy which would enable the users of the hotspot to surf without using any proxy
Is there any way that i can route the settings in the windows routing table so that all the traffic is routed from the wireless connection to a particular address and port??
I found an application called *AnalogX Proxy* which does a similar job, it implements something called "*proxy through a proxy*", 
i.e. it figures out the proxy enabled on the system itself and binds the data on a specified address to go through that proxy. 
So, instead of that address, i was hoping if anybody could tell me how i could do that in windows :)

-----The main idea----

------------------------------>>>  {[proxy]}   ------------------------->>>
(connection-- needs proxy)                 (connection--no proxy needed)

I had to post coz i couldn't find a workaround to this problem, so please bear with me n help :)
Thanks in andvance :)

--PC

Comment: Please clarify, Do you want to force all apps to use proxy without knowing it?!

Comment: @SoroushFalahati yes, that is what i want to do i.e. i wanna route the data to & from the wireless adapter interface to pass through a socket.using routing tables i can send the data to an ip but not able to send it to a socket. any idea how can that be done??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If asking as developer there are lot of ways to do this.

1. You can hook all winsocket functions in all applications and wrote your own app to route them through a socks proxy.
2. You can write a WinSocket LSP and modify all inbound and outbound data packages.
3. Creating a virtual network adapter which route all data to a proxy.

But from user perspective you can use:

1. Applications that hook into other processes like ProxyCAP (Commercial)
   http://www.proxycap.com
2. Applications which control winsocket using LSP like Proxifier (Commercial)
   http://www.proxifier.com/
3. Using OpenVPN Tap Adapter to create a virtual TAP adapter along with Tun2Socks to redirect traffics to a socks proxy and routing table to send traffics to adapter. (Completely Open Source)
   http://code.google.com/p/badvpn/wiki/tun2socks

Comment: thanks @Soroush i'm not that comfortable writing my own app in windows

Comment: @user1797102, Yeah I know and that was the reason why I introduced three application to you. You can use them without any knowledge about programming. (ProxyCap, Proxifier and Tun2Socks)

Comment: thanks @Soroush for providing many solutions :). i'm not that comfortable writing my own app in windows.regarding the third solution u gave me, infact this is wht i was asking :P. So, can u tell me, how can i route the data to the proxy from the n/w adapter that i created.Thanks once again :), i tried the other solutions with high hopes, but they didnt seem to work on my system :(

Comment: Their wiki is nearly complete and has good information: http://code.google.com/p/badvpn/wiki/tun2socks 1. First you need to install OpenVPN, you actually dont need OpenVPN it-self, You need only its drivers. Then install new tap device from start menu. After completing of installation process you need to check for any new network adapter and when you found it you need to change its ip and sub-mask. 2. Then you need to run tun2socks. read that link for more info.

Comment: 3. Last step is to add a rule to route table to route all traffics to new adapter. then you need to add an other rule to forward proxy's ip address using real internet.

Comment: thanks @Soroush :) but it didn't work out. neways, thx i'll find out some way :) thanks once again

Comment: @user1797102, I used it a lot before. Working great but it is little tricky. Any way, try and some day you can get it working.